# Why can't I simply vote to close as belonging on other SE site.. but not meta?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons

Vote to close.....

Off Topic...

Belongs on other Stack Exchange network....

I get this....

[image: meta]

Question is **not** meta related. Actually I think the question belongs on stackoverflow.

Notice I can't vote.. the button is disabled. I can select "Belongs on meta" and then vote, but that's not accurate.

Is this merely a bug in the new closing system?

Just a dumb user error on my part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the question out.

[@Yannis](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3694/yannis) gave the best answer in a comment to [John's answer](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/619/3270):

> @Scott Generally speaking, beta sites do not get migration targets (except Meta). Flag for moderation attention if you feel a question is more suitable for another site. – Yannis Jul 6 at 4:24

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember what it looked like before the closing changes, were you able to enter a site? Or just a generic "this goes somewhere else" option?

Here's what I see:

[image: Off Topic Migration]

In the meantime, what you've been doing is fine (entering a custom close comment reason). Alternatively, you could just flag it as "**it needs ♦ moderator attention**" and say where you think it should go in the box

---

Other sites have a list of commonly migrated-to places, but that's a feature that comes with graduation. See this example: [Can we have an Off-Topic > Belongs on StackOverflow option?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/995)

Comment: My screenshot shows exactly what I see... no options other than Meta. Hmm.... Chrome issue maybe?

Comment: @Scott yeah presumably mine is a "mod only" thing

Comment: That would make sense... but there should be a user option for something other than meta.

Comment: The "write your own" is a moderator option only. The same thing has come up on [Meta.ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4021/proposal-to-fix-the-uselessness-of-the-new-off-topic-close-options). Perhaps the mods can put some pressure on TPTB?

Comment: Or simply remove that last step and vote after selecting "Belongs on other network" Let the Mods determine if it's meta or something else.

Comment: @Scott Generally speaking, beta sites do not get migration targets (except Meta). Flag for moderation attention if you feel a question is more suitable for another site.